# Is there a way to obtain the duration of pandas offset aliases in days?

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I suspect there's a simple way to do this that I'm unaware of. I'd like to obtain the duration of a pandas offset alias (eg, 'W', '2M', '3D' etc) entered by the user, in days.

So what I was imagining was something like:

```
span = 'M'
num_days = pd.Period(span).days
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Or even a hard way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
per = pd.Period(pd.to_datetime('today'), freq=span)
num_days = per.asfreq('D', how='end') - per.asfreq('D', how='start')
```